# Where does Krosp's hat come from?

Tags: girl-genius

When Tarvek comes to meet the Jäger generals ([volume 12 page 81](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20120511)), he finds Krosp wearing a hat.

[image: front]
                
[image: back]

I have a feeling I've seen this hat before. Did we see it earlier in the story? Is this a cameo?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure we haven't seen it before, as the back states "Souvenir of Mechanicsberg".  I can't recall unowned hats, or hats in cat-size, appearing since they reached Mechanicsberg.

The reason it may look familiar is because the green-teethy bit looks a bit like [Winslow](http://www.thugdome.com/slagblah_winslow.htm), a "character" that has [appeared in Girl Genius before](http://www.thugdome.com/slagblah_sightings.html) (albeit not in hat form).

Comment: I'm familiar with the Winslow, and I don't see the resemblance.

Comment: The green eyes and teeth were what made me think of it, though I'm not the [only](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=0000000000000000000002oy&page=712) [one](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/girlgenius/message/77048).

Comment: Yeah, I'd googled before posting, but I'm with [Mauri](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/posts.php?discussion=0000000000000000000002oy&page=712#17787), this is no Winslow, the eyes and color are wrong. Both are greenish and drawn by Phil Foglio, but there ends the likeness.